# Illegal number when decimal point is used in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, lua

I am very new to bash scripting and I have a problem with a script.

```
#!/bin/sh
timestamp() {
        date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"
}
LOGDIR="/home/pi/tempcontroller_rum1.log"

VALUE=28

TEMP=$(cat /home/pi/temperaturloggar/rum1.txt)
STATUS=`cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value`
echo `timestamp` "  Info:    Temperature: $TEMP"        >>$LOGDIR
if [ $TEMP -le $VALUE ] && [ $STATUS -eq 0 ]
        then
        echo `timestamp` "Too Cold, Heater started."    >>$LOGDIR
        echo "1">/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
        print $TEMP
elif [ $TEMP -ge $VALUE ]  && [ $STATUS -eq 1 ]
        then
        echo `timestamp` "Warm enough, Heater stoped."  >>$LOGDIR
        echo "0">/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
        print $TEMP
fi
```

The file "rum1" contains a number that hs several decimals I think this is the problem, becouse when I runt the script I get

```
./tempcontroller_rum1.sh: 12: [: Illegal number: 25.10000038147
```

`./tempcontroller_rum1.sh: 17: [: Illegal number: 25.10000038147`

Any advice? I need the script to read from the .txt, compare it to the VALUE and then turn on/of the GPIO depending on if its lower or higher then the VALUE

If I manualy set the rum1.txt to 24. The script works, but I get the folowing warnings/errors.

`Warning: unknown mime-type for "24" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "24"`

How can I solve this?

My Lua script writing to the rum.txt can I round this up/dwn

```
commandArray = {}
if (devicechanged['Rum1']) then
    local file = io.open("/home/pi/temperaturloggar/rum1.txt", "w")
    file:write(tonumber(otherdevices_temperature['Rum1']))
    file:close()
end
return commandArray
```

Comment: Bash doesn't understand floating point numbers.

Comment: Oki, I see. Well I have a Lua script that is collectiong and writing to this rum1.txt
Is there anyway of rounding up/down this value in the lua script I have added the lua script in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bc) to do the floating point comparison:

```
$ VALUE=28
$ TEMP=25.10000038147
$ bc<<<"$TEMP < $VALUE"
1
```

In you case :

```
if [ $(bc<<<"$TEMP < $VALUE") -eq 1 ] && [ $STATUS -eq 0 ]
```

Comment: The TEMP value changes every minute, so I need it to be read from the file. Does this still work?

Comment: The values where provided only to have a full example.

Comment: Oki, I get the following  error when tryeing to add it ./tempcontroller_rum1.sh: 11: ./tempcontroller_rum1.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: Are you sure that you are using bash ?, I believe some distributions use dash as /bin/sh, wich does support the <<< notation

Comment: The shebang at the top of the script suggests otherwise. @Karl-Gunnar change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` to use bash features, or use `echo "string" | bc` rather than `bc<<<"string"` if you don't have bash.

Comment: Hmmm, in my script in post it says #!/bin/sh, if I change it to #!/bin/bash I get the following ./tempcontroller_rum1.sh: line 11: bc: command not found
./tempcontroller_rum1.sh: line 11: [: -eq: unary operator expected
./tempcontroller_rum1.sh: line 16: bc: command not found
./tempcontroller_rum1.sh: line 16: [: -eq: unary operator expected

Comment: It seems that bc is not installed, what happen if you try the first (standalone) example ?

Comment: hmm, weird, I run debian on a raspberry pi. Thought it would come preinstalled with bash. Will have to look in to sort that out.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
$ VALUE=28
$ TEMP=25.10000038147
$ bc<<<"$TEMP < $VALUE"

Gives 
./test3.sh: line 3: $: command not found

Comment: So `bc` is definetely not installed. It should be available on Raspbian

Comment: Oki, Installed bc and now script is working. Thank you!!! But I still get the: Error: no such file "24.200000762939"   How can I get rid of this? @bwt

Comment: I guess that the `print` command expect a filename, not a value (I don't know of a `print` command, did you mean `echo` ot `printf` ?)

Comment: Thank you, that is correct. I removed the print since it was no longer needed (write to logfile is enough). All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the comment, use `math.floor` to round down, as in:

```
file:write(math.floor(otherdevices_temperature['Rum1']))
```

To round up, use

```
file:write(math.floor(otherdevices_temperature['Rum1']+0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Now my script is working as it shuld and I wanted to post the code if anyone els is having the same question as me.

```
#!/bin/bash 
timestamp() {
    date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"
}
LOGDIR="/home/pi/tempcontroller_rum1.log"
VALUE=23
TEMP=$(cat /home/pi/temperaturloggar/rum1.txt)
STATUS=`cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value`
echo `timestamp` "  Info:    Temperature: $TEMP"        >>$LOGDIR
if [ $(bc<<<"$TEMP < $VALUE") -eq 1 ] && [ $STATUS -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo `timestamp` "Too Cold, Heater started."    >>$LOGDIR
    echo "1">/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
elif [ $(bc<<<"$TEMP < $VALUE") -eq 0 ] && [ $STATUS -eq 1 ]
    then
    echo `timestamp` "Warm enough, Heater stoped."  >>$LOGDIR
    echo "0">/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
fi
```

Comment: This script could be rewritten in a much better way: do not use uppercase variable names; don't use `cat`: it seems you're only reading the first line of the file, so `read -r temp < /home/pi/temperaturloggar/rum1.txt` would be much more efficient; save the value of `bc <<< "$TEMP < $VALUE"` to make your script more readable; if you're using bash≥4.2, you can use `printf` with the `%(...)T` format to avoid using the external `date`. But all this now belongs to code review.